# Updating a single row in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to update a single row of a table, specifically using a primary key value using linq.

```
 var mytab = new Customer();
 mytab.FirstName = mymodel.FirstName;
 mytab.LastName = mymodel.LastName;
 mytab.CustomerId = mymodel.CustomerId;

 db.AddToCustomer(mytab);
 db.SaveChanges()
```

This adds a new row with a new id. Stepping through the code reveals that `mymodel` is passing the correct values with a first or last name that I want to update.

The `mymodel.CustomerId` is the correct id of the record I want to update but SQL Profiler shows I'm not updating anything.  Do I need to use .First ?

Comment: LINQ isn't for updating, as in the `Q` = Query! What are you using as your backend? LINQ2SQL? LINQ2Entities?

Comment: Why have you rolled back the edit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code creates new row. For updating you need first select your Customer by id from database and then update:

```
var mytab = db.Customers.First(g=>g.CustomerId == mymodel.CustomerId);
 mytab.FirstName = mymodel.FirstName;
 mytab.LastName = mymodel.LastName;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You should really just use `First` if your next line throws a null reference exception when the OrDefault bit happens.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Agree

Comment: Interesting choice of `g` in the lambda. I usually use `x` and a lot of people use the first letter of the entity type, in this case `c` for `Customer`. Not that this has any effect on the correctness of the code.

Comment: @xdumaine I don't know if this is strange but I use the first letter of the method, e.g. For `First` I use `f`. It helps me remember which method the lambda expression is contained in (especially if the expression gets really long).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.Customer.First(x=> x.CustomerId == mymodel.CustomerId).FirstName = mymodel.FirstName;
db.Customer.First(x=> x.CustomerId == mymodel.CustomerId).LastName = mymodel.LastName;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or: (I prefer this!)

```
db.Entry(mymodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```